# How to change color for only one bar using pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Currently the color of the bar are the same. How can I change the color of the bar with the highest value?

```
df.groupby("Position")["Salary"].mean()

#Plot bar graph
ax = df.groupby("Position")["Salary"].mean().plot(kind="bar",width = 0.8, color='darkblue')

plt.xlabel("Position",fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Salary",fontsize=12)
plt.title("Wages for different job functions", fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
s = df.groupby("Position")["Salary"].mean()

s.plot.bar(color=np.where(s==s.max(), 'r','b'))
```

Output:

[image]